# How to create notification icon badge on Android apps (like iPhone)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am very new to programming and would like to know what is the best way to go about creating a notification icon badge similar to the ones on the iPhone apps. This would be basically for creating a badge for the notifications that end up in the notification bar.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually an answer from Mark Murphy:

> For most phones, you use the number field of the Notification object.
>   See here:
>   http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/Notify1/
>
> Now, there are a few phones by one major device manufacturer that have
>   a bug, whereby the number field is ignored. I am working on getting
>   them to fix it. So you can't absolutely rely on that red bubble being
>   there, though it will be on most phones.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about a graphical icon? I created a transparent PNG using the gimp and pass that drawable id as the 1st argument to the [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) constructor.

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.someicon,title,System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Comment: No. I would like to change the icon of the shortcut to the app on the home screen not the image in the notification bar.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old question. May be this link is helpful is you are still looking for answer. https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger