# How to use badge notification in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create notification icon badge on Android apps (like iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587294/how-to-create-notification-icon-badge-on-android-apps-like-iphone)

Friends in Android Possible badge notification any body know then plz help me.

thanks for advance.

[image]

Comment: i thinkk this is native iphone notfication. not possible in android. if you want the same use differet images for that.

Comment: This possible in some phone like samsung and sony not for all device because this feature provide by manufacture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible to do in Android: badges are specifically an iOS feature. On Android you use [Status Bar Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Comment: +1 You can stack Notifications so that the number appears in the status bar.  That's how we do it in Android. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) for notification,

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.someicon,title,System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try Widget.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html