# Native Badging for Android?

Tags: android, badge

I found a badge on my Android device today and I'm wondering how they did this.

Look at the "Email" icon next to "Camera" and "Talk". How are they getting the number **2** on the corner of that icon?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create notification icon badge on Android apps (like iPhone)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587294/how-to-create-notification-icon-badge-on-android-apps-like-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't support updating the app icon natively. I'm not familiar with TouchWiz, but I'm pretty sure Samsung didn't implement this either.

However you *could* create an [`AppWidget`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html), that looks like an icon. This would give you the ability to dynamically update the icon.

Comment: Yes, I've taken a look at that one. What throws me off is that the "Email" application appears to be native to Android. Is what they did considered a "custom" implementation?

Comment: Is the icon really an icon? (Not a widget?) I assume this is the default email client, that was preinstalled on the phone right?

Comment: Based on what I've seen so far, it sounds like it's probably something third party (perhaps a widget). Yes, this app was already on my phone when I got it. So is the widget I would make just *representing* the actual app? Would they have both the widget & the app installed?