# Implement badge counter for all types of android device (different launchers)

Tags: android, badge

Some home launchers, like Samsung, Sony, HTC, Nova Launcher etc., support badge counters. How can I implement badge counters for all devices that support it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create notification icon badge on Android apps (like iPhone)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587294/how-to-create-notification-icon-badge-on-android-apps-like-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

1st of all badge view is not any launcher or device specific .If you want to implement Badge View in Android 1st you have to create custom class for badge view

```
public class BadgeView extends TextView {

    public static final int POSITION_TOP_LEFT = 1;
    public static final int POSITION_TOP_RIGHT = 2;
    public static final int POSITION_BOTTOM_LEFT = 3;
    public static final int POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT = 4;
    public static final int POSITION_CENTER = 5;

    private static final int DEFAULT_MARGIN_DIP = 5;
    private static final int DEFAULT_LR_PADDING_DIP = 5;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CORNER_RADIUS_DIP = 8;
    private static final int DEFAULT_POSITION = POSITION_TOP_RIGHT;
    private static final int DEFAULT_BADGE_COLOR = Color
            .parseColor("#CCFF0000"); // Color.RED;
    private static final int DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;

    private static Animation fadeIn;
    private static Animation fadeOut;

    private Context context;
    private View target;

    private int badgePosition;
    private int badgeMarginH;
    private int badgeMarginV;
    private int badgeColor;

    private boolean isShown;

    private ShapeDrawable badgeBg;

    private int targetTabIndex;

    public BadgeView(Context context) {
        this(context, (AttributeSet) null, android.R.attr.textViewStyle);
    }

    public BadgeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.textViewStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor -
     *
     * create a new BadgeView instance attached to a target
     * {@link android.view.View}.
     *
     * @param context
     *            context for this view.
     * @param target
     *            the View to attach the badge to.
     */
    public BadgeView(Context context, View target) {
        this(context, null, android.R.attr.textViewStyle, target, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor -
     *
     * create a new BadgeView instance attached to a target
     * {@link android.widget.TabWidget} tab at a given index.
     *
     * @param context
     *            context for this view.
     * @param target
     *            the TabWidget to attach the badge to.
     * @param index
     *            the position of the tab within the target.
     */
    public BadgeView(Context context, TabWidget target, int index) {
        this(context, null, android.R.attr.textViewStyle, target, index);
    }

    public BadgeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        this(context, attrs, defStyle, null, 0);
    }

    public BadgeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle,
                     View target, int tabIndex) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, target, tabIndex);
    }

    public BadgeView(Context context, SlidingTabStrip target,
                     int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this(context, null, android.R.attr.textViewStyle, target, i);
    }

    private void init(Context context, View target, int tabIndex) {

        this.context = context;
        this.target = target;
        this.targetTabIndex = tabIndex;

        // apply defaults
        badgePosition = DEFAULT_POSITION;
        badgeMarginH = dipToPixels(DEFAULT_MARGIN_DIP);
        badgeMarginV = badgeMarginH;
        badgeColor = DEFAULT_BADGE_COLOR;

        setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        int paddingPixels = dipToPixels(DEFAULT_LR_PADDING_DIP);
        setPadding(paddingPixels, 0, paddingPixels, 0);
        setTextColor(DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR);

        fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        fadeIn.setDuration(200);

        fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        fadeOut.setDuration(200);

        isShown = false;

        if (this.target != null) {
            applyTo(this.target);
        } else {
            show();
        }

    }

    private void applyTo(View target) {

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = target.getLayoutParams();
        ViewParent parent = target.getParent();
        FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout(context);

        if (target instanceof TabWidget) {

            // set target to the relevant tab child container
            target = ((TabWidget) target).getChildTabViewAt(targetTabIndex);
            this.target = target;

            ((ViewGroup) target).addView(container, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            container.addView(this);

        } else if (target instanceof SlidingTabStrip) {

            // set target to the relevant tab child container
            View textView = ((SlidingTabStrip) target)
                    .getChildAt(targetTabIndex);

            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) target;

            // getting index of TexTView from SlidingTabStrip
            int index = group.indexOfChild(textView);

            Log.e("index", "" + index);

            group.removeView(textView);
            group.addView(container, index, lp);

            container.addView(textView);

            this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            container.addView(this);

            group.invalidate();

        } else {
            // TODO verify that parent is indeed a ViewGroup

            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) parent;
            int index = group.indexOfChild(target);

            group.removeView(target);
            group.addView(container, index, lp);

            container.addView(target);

            this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            container.addView(this);

            group.invalidate();

        }

    }

    /**
     * Make the badge visible in the UI.
     *
     */
    public void show() {
        show(false, null);
    }

    /**
     * Make the badge visible in the UI.
     *
     * @param animate
     *            flag to apply the default fade-in animation.
     */
    public void show(boolean animate) {
        show(animate, fadeIn);
    }

    /**
     * Make the badge visible in the UI.
     *
     * @param anim
     *            Animation to apply to the view when made visible.
     */
    public void show(Animation anim) {
        show(true, anim);
    }

    /**
     * Make the badge non-visible in the UI.
     *
     */
    public void hide() {
        hide(false, null);
    }

    /**
     * Make the badge non-visible in the UI.
     *
     * @param animate
     *            flag to apply the default fade-out animation.
     */
    public void hide(boolean animate) {
        hide(animate, fadeOut);
    }

    /**
     * Make the badge non-visible in the UI.
     *
     * @param anim
     *            Animation to apply to the view when made non-visible.
     */
    public void hide(Animation anim) {
        hide(true, anim);
    }

    /**
     * Toggle the badge visibility in the UI.
     *
     */
    public void toggle() {
        toggle(false, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Toggle the badge visibility in the UI.
     *
     * @param animate
     *            flag to apply the default fade-in/out animation.
     */
    public void toggle(boolean animate) {
        toggle(animate, fadeIn, fadeOut);
    }

    /**
     * Toggle the badge visibility in the UI.
     *
     * @param animIn
     *            Animation to apply to the view when made visible.
     * @param animOut
     *            Animation to apply to the view when made non-visible.
     */
    public void toggle(Animation animIn, Animation animOut) {
        toggle(true, animIn, animOut);
    }

    private void show(boolean animate, Animation anim) {
        if (getBackground() == null) {
            if (badgeBg == null) {
                badgeBg = getDefaultBackground();
            }
            setBackgroundDrawable(badgeBg);
        }
        applyLayoutParams();

        if (animate) {
            this.startAnimation(anim);
        }
        this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isShown = true;
    }

    private void hide(boolean animate, Animation anim) {
        this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (animate) {
            this.startAnimation(anim);
        }
        isShown = false;
    }

    private void toggle(boolean animate, Animation animIn, Animation animOut) {
        if (isShown) {
            hide(animate && (animOut != null), animOut);
        } else {
            show(animate && (animIn != null), animIn);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Increment the numeric badge label. If the current badge label cannot be
     * converted to an integer value, its label will be set to "0".
     *
     * @param offset
     *            the increment offset.
     */
    public int increment(int offset) {
        CharSequence txt = getText();
        int i;
        if (txt != null) {
            try {
                i = Integer.parseInt(txt.toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                i = 0;
            }
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
        i = i + offset;
        setText(String.valueOf(i));
        return i;
    }

    /**
     * Decrement the numeric badge label. If the current badge label cannot be
     * converted to an integer value, its label will be set to "0".
     *
     * @param offset
     *            the decrement offset.
     */
    public int decrement(int offset) {
        return increment(-offset);
    }

    private ShapeDrawable getDefaultBackground() {

        int r = dipToPixels(DEFAULT_CORNER_RADIUS_DIP);
        float[] outerR = new float[] { r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r };

        RoundRectShape rr = new RoundRectShape(outerR, null, null);
        ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(rr);
        drawable.getPaint().setColor(badgeColor);

        return drawable;

    }

    private void applyLayoutParams() {

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        switch (badgePosition) {
            case POSITION_TOP_LEFT:
                lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
                lp.setMargins(badgeMarginH, badgeMarginV, 0, 0);
                break;
            case POSITION_TOP_RIGHT:
                lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
                lp.setMargins(0, badgeMarginV, badgeMarginH, 0);
                break;
            case POSITION_BOTTOM_LEFT:
                lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.BOTTOM;
                lp.setMargins(badgeMarginH, 0, 0, badgeMarginV);
                break;
            case POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT:
                lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.BOTTOM;
                lp.setMargins(0, 0, badgeMarginH, badgeMarginV);
                break;
            case POSITION_CENTER:
                lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        setLayoutParams(lp);

    }

    /**
     * Returns the target View this badge has been attached to.
     *
     */
    public View getTarget() {
        return target;
    }

    /**
     * Is this badge currently visible in the UI?
     *
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isShown() {
        return isShown;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the positioning of this badge.
     *
     * one of POSITION_TOP_LEFT, POSITION_TOP_RIGHT, POSITION_BOTTOM_LEFT,
     * POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT, POSTION_CENTER.
     *
     */
    public int getBadgePosition() {
        return badgePosition;
    }

    /**
     * Set the positioning of this badge.
     *
     * @param layoutPosition
     *            one of POSITION_TOP_LEFT, POSITION_TOP_RIGHT,
     *            POSITION_BOTTOM_LEFT, POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT, POSTION_CENTER.
     *
     */
    public void setBadgePosition(int layoutPosition) {
        this.badgePosition = layoutPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the horizontal margin from the target View that is applied to
     * this badge.
     *
     */
    public int getHorizontalBadgeMargin() {
        return badgeMarginH;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the vertical margin from the target View that is applied to this
     * badge.
     *
     */
    public int getVerticalBadgeMargin() {
        return badgeMarginV;
    }

    /**
     * Set the horizontal/vertical margin from the target View that is applied
     * to this badge.
     *
     * @param badgeMargin
     *            the margin in pixels.
     */
    public void setBadgeMargin(int badgeMargin) {
        this.badgeMarginH = badgeMargin;
        this.badgeMarginV = badgeMargin;
    }

    /**
     * Set the horizontal/vertical margin from the target View that is applied
     * to this badge.
     *
     * @param horizontal
     *            margin in pixels.
     * @param vertical
     *            margin in pixels.
     */
    public void setBadgeMargin(int horizontal, int vertical) {
        this.badgeMarginH = horizontal;
        this.badgeMarginV = vertical;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the color value of the badge background.
     *
     */
    public int getBadgeBackgroundColor() {
        return badgeColor;
    }

    /**
     * Set the color value of the badge background.
     *
     * @param badgeColor
     *            the badge background color.
     */
    public void setBadgeBackgroundColor(int badgeColor) {
        this.badgeColor = badgeColor;
        badgeBg = getDefaultBackground();
    }

    private int dipToPixels(int dip) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dip,
                r.getDisplayMetrics());
        return (int) px;
    }

}
```

And wherever you want badge view just initialize and use it

```
 BadgeView badge;
```